# Show Subtotal, Tax, Grand Total in Woocommerce MINI CART

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website with the woocommerce plugin. In the woocommerce settings I have the price excluding tax displaying in the cart and checkout. So it shows the Subtotal, Tax, and Grand Total.

BUT in the Mini Cart widget it only shows the subtotal.

How can I have the Mini Cart widget show the Subtotal, Tax, and Grand Total?

Comment: Minicart is not made for that for many reasons. So you should better just forget it.