# Refresh Mini cart on shipping or payment method change in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to trigger the WooCommerce Mini Cart to update when someone changes the Shipping Method or Payment Method on the Checkout page.

I tried using the following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_minicart_checkout_jqscript' );
function custom_minicart_checkout_jqscript() {
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return; // Only Checkout Page
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

But it displays the previous total instead of the current total when customer make changes on selected Shipping Method or/and Payment Method.

**UPDATE** I tested the following solution but I'm getting the same result. [You can see it on this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cf8859LBW5tLdzwD1SBeamtDdAvLcw81/view?usp=sharing) (download video to view in high quality). I removed non-essential plugins and clear the functions.php file. It seems possible but for some reason the mini cart update is delayed by the previous total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the following instead, delegating the change event to `document.body` and targeting specifically shipping methods and payment methods changes:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'minicart_checkout_refresh_script');
function minicart_checkout_refresh_script(){
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document.body).on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"],input[name^="shipping_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout').trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

> **Note:** There is not any calculated total in mini cart, but only cart items subtotal… You can see that on WooCommerce default template [`cart/mini-cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.0/templates/cart/mini-cart.php) file. So **there is nothing to be refreshed or updated** in default WooCommerce mini cart **on checkout page**.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my code, but I'm getting the same result. On change, the mini cart updates to the previous total. So say, if the total is 29 and I change the shipping method to take take the total to 40, the mini cart updates to 29. And if I change the shipping method to something else, it then displays 40. It's almost as if the mini cart is one step-behind. I've removed all other functions to isolate the code but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting My code just answer your question and refresh successfully checkout and cart fragments on shipping or payment method change. Normally on WooCommerce mini cart there is only the cart items subtotal, but not any total. Now it seems that you have done some other customizations that are involved in your issue and that nobody can guess as you didn't provide anything related, in your question.

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting So your code is not really testable and your issue can't be reproduce. Note that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"***. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ah! I understand. I was under the impression that the mini cart total should also update if I select a shipping method (with a cost) or payment method (with a fee). I did not know that it is not possible to update the mini cart total with the order total. If that's the case then my mini cart total is working just fine without the above code. Just to confirm, you're saying it's not possible to update the minicart to reflect the order total as the shipping method or payment gateway is changed?

Comment: I just read your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439256/show-subtotal-tax-grand-total-in-woocommerce-mini-cart I'll definitely forget about it. :D

Comment: You can see my result here...https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cf8859LBW5tLdzwD1SBeamtDdAvLcw81/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So you're saying I shouldn't chase this. It's definitely not possible?

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting If you haven't made any customizations to mini cart, yes it's not really needed, as there is nothing to refresh in minicart on Checkout page.

Comment: Agreed. I just checked again and you're right. It's best to leave the mini cart as is. Thank you for indulging me.